# Слияние таблиц по общим данным в одну

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Хочу научиться объединять таблицы по заданному критерию. Допустим, в двух фреймах у меня есть повторяющиеся фамилии - я хочу вытащить их оттуда и объединить по такому типу.

Что-то вроде такого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно сформулировать запрос, чтобы найти полезную информацию по этой теме? Какая библиотека этим вообще занимается? Пока не удается найти что-нибудь полезно к прочтению.

Comment: res = df1.merge(df2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом .merge():

```
res = df1.merge(df2)
```

[Документация](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Comment: Кстати, в чём разница с `join`, никак не уясню? Или `join` это более широкий вариант, когда может не быть совпадения столбцов?

Comment: @CrazyElf, `.join()` по умолчанию объединяет по индексу